# How to mock axios with Vue Test Utils and Jest?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to run example from here: https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-asynchronous-behavior

my component:

```
<template>
  <button @click="fetchResults">{{ value }}</button>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    async fetchResults() {
      const response = await axios.get('mock/service')
      this.value = response
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

my test:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises'
import Foo from '@/components/test-axios.vue'

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: Promise.resolve('value'),
}))

it('fetches async when a button is clicked', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Foo)
  await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
  await flushPromises()
  expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('value')
})
```

and as result I'm getting error:

> TypeError: _axios.default.get is not a function

Please help, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'get' should be a function.

You could wrap the get with a jest.fn to mock the call of get to be able to test it was called.

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('value')),
}))
```

Comment: or `get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('value')`